# Javascript Loop rows and columns

Tags: javascript, image, while-loop

Ok so i have a JSON file with urls of 15 images in it.  What i am trying to achieve is something like so...

```
1-2-3
4-5-6
7-8-9
10-11-12
13-14-15
```

So that I have 3 columns and 5 rows of images.  I know i have to loop through the images to get them but how do i build them into rows so that there are 3 images in each row.  Im using simple javascript not jquery or any other framework.  Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: By 'JSON file' do you mean a JSON array or a JSON object? Could you add a sample of your JSON?

Comment: Sorry yea, its a JSON array with lots of objects within it

Comment: Are you trying to create table with three columns and five rows then append to the document, or have this in array?

Comment: going to be appending the images on a document

Comment: I would ideal like something like this but in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025387/how-to-show-nine-images-in-a-table-three-images-in-each-row-using-php

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** After re-reading the question and some of the comments, I believe the OP wants the images rendered in HTML and not simply placed in a two-dimensional array.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="images_container"></div>
```

You can take a JSON array with image data and do something like this:

```
var data = [
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3594/3498411074_f10d546f42_t.jpg',
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3364/3498396436_44bcdcc06f_t.jpg',
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3436/3356022463_cd53a9b57d_t.jpg',
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3422/3356840596_57f5da7842_t.jpg',
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3180/2776515140_b7cd27cf7e_t.jpg',
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3273/2758309734_48cfe16860_t.jpg',
    'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3156/2758267414_6320ce7bdd_t.jpg'];

var images = document.createElement("div");
images.setAttribute("id", "images");

var img;

for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    // If three images have been placed on a row,
    // create a new row.
    if (index % 3 === 0) {
        row = document.createElement("div");
        row.setAttribute("class", "images-row");
        images.appendChild(row);        
    }
    // replace 'data[index]' with the url of the image in each member of the array.
    img = createImageElement(data[index]);
    row.appendChild(img);
}

images.appendChild(row);
document.getElementById("images_container").appendChild(images);

// Creates an image element with the given url.
function createImageElement(url) {
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", url);
    img.setAttribute("alt", "image");
    return img;
}
```

**Note** that 'data' can be replaced with actual data.  I've given each image row a class of `images-row`.  Using this CSS class you could apply whatever styles you want to each row and each image in the row.

**Note also** that this code kind of assumes images of the same width and height.  The logic won't break if the images are different sizes, but the presentation will look a little funky (that's where the CSS could come in).

Comment: Ok so i have managed to modify yours to get my data into the result, now how would i go about showing these images in their rows to display like a gallery kind of thing

Comment: @ChrisMJ - what kind of gallery? Please give some example. Anyway you can work on this "live" here: http://jsfiddle.net/553cP/

Answer (score 2):

I don't guarantee this will work (i'm tired right now), but something like this should do the trick:

```
// let's say that arr == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
result = []
for(i=0; i<=arr.length-step; i+=step)
{
    row = []
    for(j=i; j<i+step && j<arr.length; i++)
        row.push(arr[j]); // or arr[j].image_url or whatever you need
    result.push(row);
}
// result is now something like [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```